# How do you make properties with interdependent values?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, properties, inotifypropertychanged

In WPF, I want to create three textboxes for the properties: FullName, FirstName and LastName. The text for these textboxes will be based on the listbox on the left (as shown in the program image below). I'm already done with getting text from the listbox to the textbox but I want to sync the values for the names such that:

changing the value for FullName, changes the listbox, FirstName and LastName box

and changing the value for FirstName and LastName changes the FullName and listbox

Here is what the program looks like:
[(Program image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0aOJ.png)

OK thanks to Jared,I was able to solve the problem by making small changes to his answer but I dont like my solution lol can someone suggest a better revision to this program?

```
    class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            FirstName = value.Split(" ".ToCharArray())?[0];
            LastName = value.Split(" ".ToCharArray())?[1];

            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            name = value + " " + LastName;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            name = FirstName + " " + value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private Course _course;

    public Course Course
    {
        get { return _course; }
        set
        {
            _course = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Course");
        }
    }


    private int _age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }
    private DateTime _birthday;

    public DateTime Birthday
    {
        get { return _birthday; }
        set
        {
            _birthday = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Birthday");
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: about the missing space between the names...that was not intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you'll need is a class such as the one below.  You'd then bind your listbox to a collection of these, and the form elements to the currently selected item.

I added a space between first and last name.  If you want that removed, you'll need to find another way of splitting the first and last names, such as checking capitalization.

Since FullName will be set regardless of which property is modified, I put all the FirePropertyChanged calls in its setter.  I haven't tested this, but I assume it will work.  :)

EDIT: Changed FullName setter to set the private variable of firstName and lastName instead of the public property.

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
        set
        {

            firstName = value.Split(" ".ToCharArray())?[0];
            lastName= value.Split(" ".ToCharArray())?[1];
            FirePropertyChanged("FullName");
            FirePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            FirePropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            FullName = value + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            FullName = FirstName + " " + value;
        }
    }

    public void FirePropertyChanged (string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but sadly it results in a StackOverFlowException

Comment: managed to solve it by making small corrections to your answer though. again, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that.  Always doing 10 things at once.  :)  The edit I made should prevent the endless loop.

Comment: Wow, this is so much better than my first solution haha thanks